# How do I access the "checked" property of a HTML checkbox element using TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, checkbox

I have the following HTML Code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check-one">
```

The following CSS code:

```
.check-one {
accent-color: #9d3039; }
```

And the following TypeScript code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  arrayName = new Array(10000);
}

const checkInput = document.getElementById('check-one') as HTMLInputElement;

console.log(checkInput.checked);
```

Whenever I view the console, all I get is an error that reads: **Uncaught TypeError: checkInput is null**

I'm wondering why this is happening? Why is it not returning either True or False since checkInput.checked is a boolean? Additionally, how to I manipulate this property so that the box can be checked and unchecked using a line of code in Typescript?

Answer (score 2):

The element does not exist when you make your query because your code gets executed when importing that TS file. The template for this component has not yet been injected into the DOM.

You need to wait until after the view is initialized before querying the DOM. You can use the `ngAfterViewInit` hook for this:

```js
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const checkInput = document.getElementById('check-one') as HTMLInputElement;
    console.log(checkInput.checked);
  }
}
```

Docs for lifecycle hooks: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

---

In an angular project, you can use a template reference and the `ViewChild` decorator to select an HTML element:

```html
<input type="checkbox" #checkOne />
```

```js
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('checkOne') _checkOne?: ElementRef;
  get checkOne(): HTMLInputElement | undefined {
    return this._checkOne?.nativeElement;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.checkOne?.checked);
  }
}
```

This is safer since you know exactly which element is being selected and it's easier to make repetitive calls.

---

As for setting the value of `checked` it's pretty simple from there:

```js
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('checkOne') _checkOne?: ElementRef;
  get checkOne(): HTMLInputElement | undefined {
    return this._checkOne?.nativeElement;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.checkOne) {
      console.log(this.checkOne.checked);
      this.checkOne.checked = true;
      console.log(this.checkOne.checked);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use onChange attribute to trigger a action when checked

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<%=item._id%>" onChange="this.form.submit()">
```

and later you can use the name attribute to target the value attribute

Answer (score 0):

I realy suggest to use:

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="check_box_value" />
```

to bind the property check_box_value to manipulate state on dom.

Answer (score -1):

when you call them,at time it doesn't render to html element,call it on ngOnit
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNZmC.png)

Comment: It should be ngAfterViewInit since this hook will be called after the DOM is rendered

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).